# Firestore .where never returns result if there aren't data Flutter Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to get all user posts from Firestore by user uid.

But if I use filter with .where inside -> get userPosts -> databaseReference.where...

Like this commented line

```
  Stream<List<PostData>> get userPosts {
    return databaseReference
    // .where('uid', isEqualTo: this.user.uid)
```

and if there aren't any posts in Firebase, it never and nothing return, just loading all the time. But if I remove/comment this line

```
// .where('uid', isEqualTo: this.user.uid)
```

it returns [] and everything is ok (even if there aren't any posts in Firebase!).

Why does this happen?

I think in the first case it returns null? If so, why in the second case without .where('uid', isEqualTo: this.user.uid) it returns not null? How can I fix it or return not null manually? Why if I add .where('uid', isEqualTo: this.user.uid) and there aren't posts in Firebase with this uid it doesn't return not null?

Yes, I can filter posts inside -> _postListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot), as I do now. But I don't want to get ALL posts from Firebase and filter them inside _postListFromSnapshot().

How can I add .where filter if there aren't any posts return just empty List, like []?

```
  Stream<List<PostData>> get userPosts {
    return databaseReference
    this line -> // .where('uid', isEqualTo: this.user.uid)
```

Here all my code:

```
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance.collection('posts');
...
// get user posts stream
  Stream<List<PostData>> get userPosts {
    return databaseReference
        // .where('uid', isEqualTo: this.user.uid)
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_postListFromSnapshot);
  }

  // post list from snapshop
  List<PostData> _postListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents
        .where((doc) => doc.data['uid'] == user.uid)
        .map((doc) {
      return PostData(
          date: doc.data['date'] ?? DateTime.now(),
          text: doc.data['text'] ?? '',
          email: doc.data['email'] ?? ''
    }).toList();
  }

//And here I listen to Stream and show Loading or PostsScreen
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final posts = Provider.of<List<PostData>>(context);
    if (posts == null) {
      return Loading();
    } else {
      return PostsScreen();
    }...
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/issues/290) The same issue was reported by a user

The solution to the Issue is to Add exemption to your firestore